What is this mysterious bar in my hotel shower?
I'm staying at a rather nice hotel and the enormous shower has a diagonal bar (pictured below) in one corner, about one foot in length and mounted about a foot off the floor.

What is the purpose of this? It's not at a useful height for balancing yourself,
it's too small for sitting, and way too low for eg hanging wet clothes.

Only vaguely related, but still pretty funny: I recently heard a bidet referred to as a “footbath”

For metric-only readers, "about one foot" is "about 30 cm."  More precisely, one foot is 30.48 cm.

It's about a foot! A footrest for shaving your legs, or drying them.
You can get them at B & Q and other places, such as Kitchens and Bathrooms UK which has this picture


It's unfortunate that they don't have a thirty-and-twelve-twenty-fifths-centimeterrest for the metric people.

@phoog this one is 350mm if you have slightly larger feet :)
